# System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: 'The content type application/xml

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have added a service reference to the third party webservice and on making a WCF call from my console application, I get the error message below:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: 'The content type application/xml; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 610 bytes of the response were: '<?xml version="1.0"?>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:CancelServiceResponse">

<soapenv:Body>

<tns:CancelServiceResponse>

<CancelServiceResult>

<Status_Code>FAILED</Status_Code>

                <Status_Description>Service_ID= not found.</Status_Description>

                <Order_ID></Order_ID>

</CancelServiceResult>

</tns:CancelServiceResponse>

</soapenv:Body>

</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Config file as below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IB2BService">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://thirdpartyendpointaddress"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IB2BService"
            contract="b2bService.IB2BService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IB2BService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Can someone advise, what needs to be done to fix this issue? I have searched all over SO and have not been able to find how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem the code snippets seem to me. One thing must be noted is to make sure the binding is consistent between the server and the client and has the correct service endpoint. On the client end, we could generate the configuration with Adding service reference tool. What I consider the best reply is to give you an example of invocation service with TransportWithMessageCredential.
**Server end (10.157.13.69. Console application)**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://localhost:11011");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;

            using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), uri))
            {
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
                smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb == null)
                {
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                    {
                        HttpsGetEnabled = true
                    };
                    sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                }
                sh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
                sh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new CustUserNamePasswordVal();
                Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding();
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");

                sh.Opened += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is ready");
                };
                sh.Closed += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is clsoed");
                };


                sh.Open();

                Console.ReadLine();
                sh.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello();
    }
    public class MyService : IService
    {
        public string SayHello()
        {
            return $"Hello Stranger,{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
        }
    }
    internal class CustUserNamePasswordVal : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (userName != "jack" || password != "123456")
            {
                throw new Exception("Username/Password is not correct");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Bind the certificate to the port.**

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:11011 certhash=6e48c590717cb2c61da97346d5901b260e983850 appid={ED4CE60F-6B2E-4EE6-828F-C1A6A1B12565}
```

**Client end (calling service by adding service reference)**

```
var client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "jack";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "123456";
            try
            {
                var result = client.SayHello();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
```

**Configuration file(auto-generated)**

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://10.157.13.69:11011/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
        </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should add that if I make the soap call using SoapUI, it works without any issues. Only via Visual Studio I get the error.

Comment: if you invoke the service by Adding Service Reference, could you update the service reference to update the appconfig?  In addition, how do you process the server certificate Validation Callback (do your server certificate use self-signed?). if the TLS version is not supported by Dotnetframework, Consider using the following code on client end.
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate
            {
                return true;
            };